# Is URT (universal runtime) equivalent to .net framework

Tags: .net

Just curious to ask. If those two are equivalent.

Comment: From some quick searches, it seems like "URT" might have been an early name for the CLR (common language runtime).  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: URT, from my research, is more the concept behind technologies like the CLR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Kind of. The Java VM is a better example, but the .NET Framework has some of these elements.

The idea of the "universal run-time" is an environment in which programs written for the runtime live and work, that can be ported to various hardware/OS environments without the program knowing the difference.

Java fits this description quite nicely. You can write Java programs that will execute just about anywhere; on any desktop or laptop, Android mobile devices, even embedded in web browsers. The language, and others that compile for use in the Java VM, will work on any hardware that has a Java VM, and where the necessary libraries are supported (different devices will have different I/O possibilities and graphics capabilities, for instance).

.Net... not quite so much. .NET will run on any "living" (still-supported) Windows OS, and on Windows Mobile devices, and there are workalikes (Mono) for Linux/Mac and ports of the C# language to compile for Android and Obj-C (iPhone) environments, but .NET itself is a Windows-only platform, and so, despite the platform's popularity, not truly "universal". However, within the bounds of the Windows environment, .NET works beautifully to "abstract" details that change even between OS versions, and allows multiple languages to compile down to the MSIL that the runtime actually digests to native code, allowing one runtime to handle projects whose source code is in different, even custom, languages. That is quite a big chunk of the URT concept.

Answer (score 0):

"Universal Run Time" was a very early name for the CLR.  Its name got preserved in the Windows SDK WinError.h include file.  Error codes generated by the CLR have facility code 19.  Like 0x80131506, the infamous Fatal Execution Engine error.

```
#define FACILITY_URT                     19
```

There's more history like this in error codes, they are archeological artifacts that preserve quite well.  The exception code for a managed exception is 0xe0434f4d.  The last 3 hex pairs spell "COM" in ASCII, an otherwise common technique used by Microsoft to pick memorable exception codes.  Quite ironic considering that the .NET framework was designed to be a replacement for COM.  But the CLR started out as a project in Microsoft's COM+ group.